# How to play a SystemSound when the ios app is in the background using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following test code working well in the foreground:

```
struct ContentView: View {

let timer = Timer.TimerPublisher(interval: 1.0, tolerance: 1.0, runLoop: .main, mode: .default)
let future10 = Date().addingTimeInterval(10)

var body: some View {
    Text("10 beeps, 10 seconds from now")
        .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
            let diff = abs(Date().timeIntervalSince(self.future10))
            if diff <= 5 {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1205)
            }
    }.onAppear(perform: {self.timer.connect()})
}
}
```

I have set the target app with "Background Modes" -> "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture"

But I can't hear the sound after I dismiss the app. The timer seems to keep going, but no sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you terminate your app its erased from memory and therefore cant execute its code.

The documentation of apple states that:

> With this capability enabled, your app’s audio can continue when users
>   switch to another app or when they lock their iOS devices.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/creating_a_basic_video_player_ios_and_tvos/enabling_background_audio

They explicitly do not mention that the app can play a sound when the app is erased from memory.

Comment: perhaps I used the wrong word here (dismiss) to describe what I'm doing.
I "swipe" my test app, quick up motion of the finger.
This I believe puts my test app in the background, not erase from memory. This is the only way I know of switching to another app.